# Indicator Functions with Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Let $E$ be an event and $Y$ a random variable.  What exactly is meant by $\mathrm E[\mathbf 1_E \mathbf 1_{Y\in B}]$?  I have two guesses, the first is that $\mathbf 1_{Y\in B}$ is an indicator random variable and the second is that $\mathbf 1_{Y\in B}$ is really a composition of an indicator function and a random variable (hence a random variable):

\begin{align*}
\mathrm E[\mathbf 1_E \mathbf 1_{Y\in B}] & = \int_{\Omega} \mathbf 1_E(\omega) \mathbf 1_{Y^{-1}(B)}(\omega)\, \mathrm dP(\omega) \\
\mathrm E[\mathbf 1_E \mathbf 1_{Y\in B}] & = \int_{\Omega} \mathbf 1_E(\omega) (\mathbf 1_B \circ Y)(\omega)\, \mathrm dP(\omega)
\end{align*}

I think it's the first line, since then we could write 
$$
\mathbf 1_E(\omega) \mathbf 1_{Y^{-1}(B)}(\omega) = \mathbf 1_{E\, \cap\, Y^{-1}(B)}(\omega) = 
\begin{cases}
1, \omega \in E\, \cap\, Y^{-1}(B), \\
0, \omega \notin E\, \cap\, Y^{-1}(B).
\end{cases}
$$
I'm not sure how we could write this for the second line, or even if it would make sense to try.

Also, assuming the first line is correct I don't immediately see how it would be possible to write this using the distribution measure of $Y$, $Y_*[P]$.  For example, if we only had $\mathrm E[\mathbf 1_{Y\in B}]$, I would like to think of this as an indicator function and write
$$
\mathrm E[\mathbf 1_{Y\in B}] = \int_\Omega (\mathbf 1_{B} \circ Y)(\omega)\, \mathrm dP(\omega) = \int_{Y(\Omega)} \mathbf 1_B(y)\, \mathrm d(Y_*[P])(y)
$$

On the other hand I guess we can use the definition of regular conditional probability to write the integral w.r.t. the distribution of $Y$:
$$
\mathrm E[\mathbf 1_E \mathbf 1_{Y\in B}] = P(E \cap \{Y \in B\}) = \int_B P^Y(E \mid y)\, \mathrm d(Y_*[P])(y)
$$
where the second equality is the definition of the regular conditional probability of $P$ given $Y$, $P^Y$.  Would this be the proper thing to do?

Comment: First part: $\mathbf 1_{Y^{-1}(B)}=\mathbf 1_B\circ Y$ hence the two suggestions are equivalent. Second part: Indeed the distribution of $Y$ does not suffice to compute $P(E\cap\{Y\in B\})$. That is, it suffices only in the specific case when $E$ belongs to $\sigma(Y)$, that is, when $E=Y^{-1}(C)$ for some measurable $C$, and then of course, $$E(\mathbf 1_E\mathbf 1_{Y^{-1}(B)})=P(E\cap\{Y\in B\})=P(Y^{-1}(C\cap B))=Y_*(P)(C\cap B).$$ But for general events $E$, there is no such formula.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\mathbf{1}_E$ denotes an indicator variable which is equal to 1 if the event $E$ holds, and to 0 otherwise. In your case, there are two events, $E$ and $Y \in B$. The expression $\mathbf{!}_E \mathbf{!}_{Y \in B}$ is simply the *product* of the two indicator variables. All in all, it equals the probability that both $E$ happens and $Y \in B$.